# Swig: Error - undefined symbol: _ZN7QString11shared_nullE

Tags: python, pyqt

I am a newbie to SWIG.. I am just trying out a simple application of my project to implement the SWIG.

The code is shown below:

test.cpp :

```
#include "dijsdk.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include "arraysize.h"
#inlcude "test.h"

int findcam()
{
error_t result = E_OK;
error_t result1;
QString m_guids[16];
DijSDK_CamGuid guids[ARRAYSIZE(m_guids)] = {0};    
unsigned int numGuids = ARRAYSIZE(guids);
result = DijSDK_Init();   //API call
if (result ==0)
    result1 = DijSDK_FindCameras(guids, &numGuids); //API call

std::cout<<"\nNumguids = " <<numGuids;
std::cout<<"\nResult = "<<result1;
std::cout<<"\nGuids = "<<guids[0];

return 0;
}
```

test.h:

```
/*File test.h*/
int findcam();
```

test.i :

```
%module test

%{
#include "dijsdk.h"
#include "arraysize.h"
#inlcude "test.h"
%}

int findcam();
```

Here the dijsdk.h and arraysize.h are third party header files.

After creating all these files, I executed the command

```
$ swig -c++ -python test.i
```

This creates test_wrap.cxx and test.py file

I am trying to create the .so file using  disutils

setup.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

test_module = Extension('_test',
                           sources=['test_wrap.cxx', 'test.cpp'],
                           )

setup (name = 'example',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "SWIG Docs",
       description = """Simple swig example from docs""",
       ext_modules = [test_module],
       py_modules = ["test"],
       )
```

I just referred this [link](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn10) and created this files, I may be wrong somewhere in the script plz correct me.

Since my test.cpp file includes qt headers and third party files I compiled the files by including their paths in the variable CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The content of CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH is:

```
"/usr/include/python2.7/,/usr/include/qt4,/usr/include/qt4/QtCore,/usr/include/qt4/QtGui,/home/user/Desktop/SwingTest/"
```

All these steps creates a successful _test.so file. Now While importing this _test.so file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    _test = swig_import_helper()
  File "test.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_test', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: ./_test.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7QString11shared_nullE
```

From the error I can see that its a QT linking error. Eventhough I am including the path in the variable CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH why its still failing?

Any help would be really appreciated....